# Accept request to a specific sub directory but redirect request to root to another URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need to setup a (basic) redirect rule but i'm totally not into redirect rules at all, so i could use a hand:

Accept requests to a specific sub directory like www.foo.com/bar (internal redirect to webroot) but send all other request (incl. www.foo.com/) to another url (server).

Thanks: Lars

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bar/?(.*)$ /$1 [L]
RewriteRule . http://www.anotherserver.com/ [L,R=301]
```